# SQL Server add respository

Tags: apt, server, sql

I am following the instructions here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017

I am trying to run step 2.

I get the result "Error '' invalid"

Could anyone advise what the problem might be or how I might be able to find out the cause? I am fairly new Linux and have very limited knowledge of installing packages. Part of the reason for installing this is to improve my Linux knowledge.

Comment: *"I am trying to run step 2"* please [edit] your question to include the exact command you tried and the complete verbatim error message

Comment: I think that is actually a warning even though it states that it is an error. You can verify that the step was successful by running the command listed in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The error you received is a "dummy error" and should be ignored.

Run the following command to verify:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep micro
```

you should see an output that says something like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-preview xenial main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-preview xenial main
```

**If you see the output**, proceed to the next step in your original microsoft instructions (step 3). You are done with step 2 and you can safely ignore the error.

---

**EDIT**

Run the following command to add apt support for https:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```

Then run the following command:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then proceed with the microsoft instructions.

If you still get a 404 error. There is something wrong with your network or DNS configuration and you should ask this as a separate question as it is not related to your original error.

---

**EDIT 2**

In the error, you show a different URL than the URL you used with `curl`.

Use the command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to edit the file and make sure that the line near the end of the file reads exactly as follows:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-preview xenial main
```

Edit the file as needed. The easiest thing to do is copy and paste instead of typing to avoid typing errors. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into the terminal.

When you are done, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the changes and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit `nano`.

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply, I thought I would get an email when people commented. Thanks for your help. I have the output you showed from the grep micro command. I also tried the echo command and can see the file it created. When I run step 3 it says unable to locate the package. I will continue to try and solve it but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I might have found something. The output of sudo apt-get update gives me (amongst other output)  https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list@/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found. However I can curl the url https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list and it seems to match /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2017.list. Am I looking for a typing error somewhere or something more fundamental?

Comment: @user983325 Delete the file: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server-2017.list` The original error (the one in your question) was a dummy error and should be ignored.

Comment: @user983325 I have edited the answer.

Comment: @user983325 In the error, you show a different URL than the URL you used with curl. Use `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure the line reads exactly: `deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-preview xenial main` You can delete the existing line and you can copy and paste this line in to be sure. Press CTRL+o to save the file and CTRL+x to exit nano and then run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying to use the 2017 install rather than the preview. My /etc/apt/sources.list file currently has: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main

Comment: @user983325 Okay, do you still get the error? If so, please edit your question and copy and paste the entire output in the question. You can use CTRL+SHIFT+c to copy from the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: @user983325 Are you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: @user983325 Also, are you using i386 ubuntu or amd64? Run the command: `uname -m` and it should say `x86_64`

Comment: This was the issue - 32bit instead of 64 bit. Thanks for your help. If I need to mark your answer in some way to give you credit then please let me know. I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 1):

I had accidently installed a 32bit (i386) version and not 64bit. Cause identified by mchid in the comments.

Under 64bit it worked fine.